# React component realtime mod

Tags: javascript, eclipse, reactjs

I'm new with React so this question may be a big misunderstanding about how things is done correctly.

I inherit an application build with Python, Django and React.

The React components files are stored in the js folder.
To compile all .js inside the folder, I have to run:

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js
```

This command compiles every *.js, so every modification to the code will be available on the site.

Questions:

- Is there a method to get the source mods online without compiling every time?
- If there is not a method for check realtime mods, is there a method to compile only the .js I'm modifying?
- Am I doing the things in the right methodology or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: You could specify the watch property: https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#watch-options. So something like ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch --config webpack.config.js should do the trick. You could also take a look @ https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server for spinning up a dev-server.

Comment: The watch option seems works but it compiles every file. Is there a method specify what file to watch so it compile only the one im working on?

Comment: You might want to take a look at Hot Reloading https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/hot-module-replacement-with-webpack, let me know if this is what you're after.

Comment: Hi. Stil not working. I think my project has a non-standard structure. I have create another question with a lot of info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48278991/django-react-webpack-dev-server