# DJANGO + REACT + WEBPACK-DEV-SERVER

Tags: python, django, reactjs

I've big problem with a project I inherit without documentation.
The project is build with Django and React.

This is the project structure (without not important stuffs):

```
myapp/
├── assets
│   ├── bundles
│   │   ├── bar.js
│   │   ├── bar.js.map
│   │   ├── login.js
│   │   ├── login.js.map
│   │   ├── main.js
│   │   ├── main.js.map
│   │   ├── messages
│   │   │   └── assets
│   │   │       └── js
│   │   │           ├── appbar.json
│   │   │           [...]
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   │   ├── [...]
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── appbar.js     <<<--- REACT COMPONENT!!!
│   │   ├── [...] <<<--- OTHER REACTS COMPONENTS!!
├── conf
│   ├── default_settings.py
│   ├── default_settings.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   └── wsgi.py
├── core
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── color_palette.py
│   ├── color_palette.pyc
│   ├── constants.py
│   ├── constants.pyc
│   ├── decorators.py
│   ├── decorators.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── utils.py
│   ├── utils.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── manage.py
├── node_modules
│    ├ webpack-dev-server   <<<--- IS INSTALLED HERE WITH AL LOT OF OTHER STUFFS
│    [...]
├── package.json
├── templates
│   ├── index.html
│   └── login.html
├── webpack.config.js
└── webpack-stats.json
```

Im currently using apache2 to run the site with the following VirtualHost config:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /usr/local/myapp/conf/wsgi.py process-group=myapp-wsgi-daemon
WSGIDaemonProcess myapp-wsgi-daemon processes=2 threads=15 display-name=myapp-wsgi python-path=/usr/local/myapp:/usr/local/dash2-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup  myapp-wsgi-daemon
```

I can access the app with the url: https://localhost/myapp/

It's very good but when I modify React Componen (see appbar.js in the tree above) I have to launch this command to see the results:

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js
```

That compile all the .js inside the directory to build assets/bundles.

The webpack.config.js is the following:

```
//require our dependencies
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')
var ReactIntlPlugin=require('react-intl-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  //the base directory (absolute path) for resolving the entry option
  context: __dirname,

  //your current directory. You don't have to specify the extension now,
  //because you will specify extension later in the `resolve` section
  entry: {
    main: './assets/js/index.js',
    login: './assets/js/login.js'
  },

  output: {
    //where you want your compiled bundle to be stored
    path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'),
    //naming convention webpack should use in your files
    filename: '[name].js',
  },

  plugins: [
    //tells webpack where to store data about your bundles.
    new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
    new ReactIntlPlugin()
  ],

  devtool: "source-map",

  module: {
    loaders: [
      //a regexp that tells webpack use the following loaders on all
      //.js and .jsx files
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,

        //we definetely don't want babel to transpile all the files in
        //node_modules. That would take a long time.
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        //use the babel loader
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          //specify that we will be dealing with React code
          presets: ['react']
        }
      },
      //loaders for css stylesheets
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      },
      //loader for font files (used by fontawesome, etc)
      {
          test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
          loader: 'url-loader?limit=30000&name=[name]-[hash].[ext]'
      },
      //babel loader for internationalization
      {
          test: /\.js?$/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          query: {
              "cacheDirectory": true,
              "metadataSubscribers":[ReactIntlPlugin.metadataContextFunctionName],
              "plugins": ["transform-runtime",
                  ["react-intl", {
                      "enforceDescriptions": false,
                      //directory where intermediate files are stored for internationalization
                      "messagesDir": "./assets/bundles/messages/",
                  }]],
              "presets": ['react', "es2015", "stage-1"]
          }
      },
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    //tells webpack where to look for modules
    modules: ['node_modules'],
    //extensions that should be used to resolve modules
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsxs']
  }
}
```

Searching on google and in this site, the only solution to HOT RELOAD the Reacts Component is installing webpack-dev-server.

I followed a lot of tutorial but the best things I get is a directory listing.

This is the command Im using to launch dev-server:

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server -d --hot --htt --config webpack.config.js
```

Im still not sure what content-base parameter I have to set in the launch command :(

Please, help me. Im out of ideas!

Thank you!!

Comment: I see this is an old question. Were you able to figure it out?  It seems that running webpack should recompile the needed files.  Is that not happening?

Comment: Unfortunally I was not able to resolve the issues but a complete refactor of project allow me to separate the React half to the Django half. The speak by rest call and in development mode one start with npm start on nodejs and the other in django dev server so hot code submit is avaiable.

Answer (score 0):

Read this please. I wish it could be useful for you:

[Using Webpack transparently with Django + hot reloading React components as a bonus](http://owaislone.org/blog/webpack-plus-reactjs-and-django/)

You should install some python libraries:

```
pip install django-webpack-loader
```

Above mentioned tutorial is good I think.